# Is it possible to suspend a Celery beat task but have other beat tasks still work?

Tags: python, task, celery, celerybeat

```
celery_app.conf.update(
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'taskA': {
'task': 'crawlerapp.tasks.manual_crawler_update',
'schedule': timedelta(seconds=3600),
},
'taskB': {
'task': 'crawlerapp.tasks.auto_crawler_update_day',
'schedule': timedelta(seconds=3600),
},
'taskC': {
'task': 'crawlerapp.tasks.auto_crawler_update_hour',
'schedule': timedelta(seconds=3600),
},
})
```

There are 3 beat tasks in my application. When the beat tasks run, I use `flower` to manage the tasks.

When I find that there is a bug in one task, I must stop the whole task to modify the bug. Then I restart Celery.

Is it possible to just stop the one task and let the other tasks continue running?

Comment: It's always important to tell people [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), including snippets of any failed attempts so that they can understand what avenues you have missed. It's important because it motivates people to answer and it's important because it makes it *easier* to give high quality, relevant answers. With the current state of the question, this hasn't been achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. One way is to queue 3 tasks in different queues and have different workers to run tasks.

By this whenever you have any problem with any task, you can stop the corresponding worker. Fix the issue and run the worker again. So the other two workers will be executing the tasks as usual.

For example, schedule a periodic task like this

```
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from celery.schedules import crontab

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute=0, hour='*/1'), queue='q1',
               options={'queue': 'q1'})
def taskA():
    #do something
```

and start worker with

```
celery -A your_app worker -l info -Q q1 -B
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django, one way is to consider using djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler. Your schedules will be stored in the DB. You can enable/disable specific schedules using the 'enabled' column in the table that stores the schedules. I've used this approach.